# How To Add Dynamic Font Size about Multi Device in Xcode Story Board

Tags: xcode, swift, responsive-design, storyboard, size

I added autoLayout in storyBoard (w: Any, h: Any)

But because of fixed font size, The font size is same in all of devices 
(4, 4.7, 5.5 inch)

It looks nice in 4 inch. But in 5.5 inch, That's too small

I want to dynamically inclease and decrease UIlabel font size in any devices.

Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I Found Solution

I Made one Class

```
class UILabelDeviceClass : UILabel {

@IBInspectable var iPhoneFontSize:CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        overrideFontSize(iPhoneFontSize)
    }
}

func overrideFontSize(fontSize:CGFloat){
    let currentFontName = self.font.fontName
    var calculatedFont: UIFont?
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let height = bounds.size.height
    switch height {
    case 480.0: //Iphone 3,4,SE => 3.5 inch
        calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize * 0.7)
        self.font = calculatedFont
        break
    case 568.0: //iphone 5, 5s => 4 inch
        calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize * 0.8)
        self.font = calculatedFont
        break
    case 667.0: //iphone 6, 6s => 4.7 inch
        calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize * 0.9)
        self.font = calculatedFont
        break
    case 736.0: //iphone 6s+ 6+ => 5.5 inch
        calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize)
        self.font = calculatedFont
        break
    default:
        print("not an iPhone")
        break
    }

}
```

}

Then, Set Class

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

And Then, Set Value

Happy Coding!

Comment: Good solution, but doesn't consider landscape orientation. Perhaps you could use `height = max(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width)`

Answer (score 2):

Check the screen size and manipulate the font size based on it:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

if screenSize.height < 568 {
    //Set font size for 4
} else if screenSize.height < 568 {
    //Set font size for 5
} else if screenSize.height < 568 {
    //Set font size for 6
} else {
    //Set font size for 6+
}
```

UPDATE:

Extend the UILabel class to setup your label:

```
extension UILabel { 
    func setupLabelDynamicSize(size size:CGFloat) {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

        if screenSize.height < 568 {
            //Set self.font equal size
        } else if screenSize.height < 568 {
            //Set self.font equal size + 1
        } else if screenSize.height < 568 {
            //Set self.font equal size + 2
        } else {
            //Set self.font equal size + 3
        }
    }
}
```

then wherever you have a label that you want with dynamic size just call:

```
labelObject.setupLabelForDynamicSize(size: 14)
```

Comment: I Thought This way. But I Can't use This. Because i have 20 View and more label. This Label Size All different.

Comment: That's very nice Idea. But I have 200s more label. Do I have to call this method for All of these labels?

Comment: Provided all labels in the app have the same text size, you could override the UILabel initialiser and call it in there

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't config size class for iPhone 5.5 only. Size class can not distinguish iPhone 5, 6 vs 6Plus.

Only 1 edge case supports for iPhone 5.5 landscape only: 
`regular width, compact height: 5.5" iPhone in Landscape`

The only way you can do it is check device size in you code !

Comment: Straight up No is very rarely a good answer. In this case, it is possible anyway. Simply check the phone size and sent the font size in code depending on the size of the phone

Comment: Yes, I know that you can check it in code, but @Yoohogyun asked: `How can do it in storyboard` ? Anyway, I'll update my answer

Comment: So Is it impossible to config in Story board? But in this case, i has Too many UIlabel. So if i"ll use Code, Then Code length Will be Too Long. If I'll using code, How Can i short Coding? Any Ideas?

Comment: I have 1 idea but it's not really good. Subclass UILabel, add a property `customTag` and create `IBDesignable` for this property. In the interface builder, set same `customTag` for UILabel (s) have the same font size. In your code, check the `customTag` and set the appropriate font size. But it's not really good !

Answer (score -1):

WIth xcode 7.3, you can click add  '+' in Attributes inspector to select font size each device
[image]

Comment: No, this doesn't work. This does apply only to different size classes. You can't distinguished iPhone5 screen size and iPhone6 screen size.

Comment: @Andrej Right. My Question Is in Same size classes