# Different UIFont sizes for different iOS devices in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, uifont

I'm developing swift based iOS application for iPhone family. My application supports all devices start from iPhone 4s to iPhone X. Labels appears bigger in smaller devices like iPhone 4s as I added bigger font size for high end devices. Can someone help me on how to scale the font according to device. I tried size classes with compact/regular width and compact/regular height but none of them helped me. Your help is very much appreciated

[image: Storyboard font setting]
[image: Rendering app on different devices]

Comment: Better you show what you tried, there are many posts about this in stack overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138926/how-to-add-dynamic-font-size-about-multi-device-in-xcode-story-board

Comment: Is there any way to set this up with storyboard itself rather than writing code and mapping font sizes ?

Answer (score 5):

**Programmatically**

Without using the storyboard I have the approach to simply change the font size depending on the screen width like so:

```
func dynamicFontSize(_ FontSize: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let calculatedFontSize = screenWidth / 375 * FontSize
    return calculatedFontSize
}
```

and can be used as:

```
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: dynamicFontSize(20))
```

Note that in the `dynamicFontSize` function the number *375* is simply the basis for the font size calculation, because I usually test my app on iPhone 8 (i.e. font size 18 *is* actually 18 on an iPhone 8 due to its actual width of 375). This number can be altered to your liking.

**Storyboard**

If you insist on using storyboard, you can instead create a new swift file subclassing `UILabel` and use an `@IBInspectable` like so:

```
import UIKit

class UILabelFontClass: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var DynamicFontSize: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            overrideFontSize(FontSize: DynamicFontSize)
        }
    }

    func overrideFontSize(FontSize: CGFloat){
        let fontName = self.font.fontName
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let calculatedFontSize = screenWidth / 375 * FontSize
        self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: calculatedFontSize)
    }
}
```

Inside storyboard subclass `UILabelFontClass` to your label:
[image: Subclassing_UILabelFontClass]

And now in the Attributes inspector, you can set the font size:
[image: Attributes_inspector_set_fontsize]

Answer (score 3):

You can try label hight according to view in storyboard .

with this image reference i done with iPhone 5s screen size and give label hight equal to hight in multiplier 30/554

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering is this a best practice ? My app supports close to 25 controllers and no approximate count on number of labels. In case to change in future this may be overwork. BTW thanks for this

Comment: Programmatically setting it would be most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making different class for UILabel. You can make **UILabel** **Extension** and use this **IBDesignable Solution** to set values from Storyboard.

Here Base width is 375pt

```
extension UILabel{
     @IBInspectable
     var scaleSize: CGFloat {
        set {
            let fontName = self.font.fontName
            let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
            let calculatedFontSize = screenWidth / 375 * newValue
            self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: calculatedFontSize)
        }
        get {
            return self.scaleSize
        }
    }
}
```