# Xamarin forms design looks compressed in iphone 5s

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have xamarin forms app.I have a screen which looks nice on iphone 6.But in Iphone 5 , it look like compressed.How to solve this design issue? In bigger devices the design works fine.

**[image: Iphone 6]**

[image: Iphone 5s]

**My XAML**

```
<Grid RowSpacing="1" x:Name="DetailsCardview" IsVisible="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#772F4F4F" Margin="10,2,10,2">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <Image Source="invoiceby.png"  HeightRequest="25" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
                    <Label Text="Invoice Details"  TextColor="LightGreen" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                        <Label.FontFamily>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Label.FontFamily>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>

                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >                              
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Invoice No"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                        <Label x:Name="InvoiceNumber" Text="-" MaxLines="1"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                             
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Customer"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                        <Label x:Name="CustomerName" Text="-" MaxLines="1" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                         
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Sold By" TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                        <Label x:Name="SoldBy" Text="-" MaxLines="1"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                               
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Sold On"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0" >
                        <Label Text="-" x:Name="SoldOn" MaxLines="2" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                              
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Invoiced By"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                        <Label Text="-" x:Name="InvoicedBy" MaxLines="1"   TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                             
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Referred By"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0" >
                        <Label Text="-" x:Name="ReferredBy" MaxLines="1" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                   <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                               
                        <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                        <Label Text="Current Carrier"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                        <Label Text="-" x:Name="CurrentCarrier" MaxLines="1" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>


    <Grid Grid.Row="1">             
                    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#772F4F4F" Margin="10,2,10,7">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                <Image Source="tracking.png"  HeightRequest="25" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
                                <Label Text="Tracking Details"  TextColor="LightGreen" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Grid  >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                                           
                                    <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                                    <Label Text="Tracking No"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                                    <Label Text=":" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TrackingNo}" x:Name="TrackingNo" TextColor="White" MaxLines="1"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                                           
                                    <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                                    <Label Text="Product Name"    TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
                                    <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" x:Name="ProductName" MaxLines="2"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                                          
                                    <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                                    <Label Text="Comments"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout  Grid.Column="1"   Grid.Row="2" >
                                    <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="2"   Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding InvoiceComments}" x:Name="Comments" MaxLines="1" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                               <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                                          
                                    <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                                    <Label Text="Refund"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout  Grid.Column="1"   Grid.Row="3" >
                                    <Label Text=":" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="3"   Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Refund}" x:Name="Refund" TextColor="White" MaxLines="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                                         
                                    <Label FontSize="Micro"  Text="⚬" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                                    <Label Text="Quantity"  TextColor="LightBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout  Grid.Column="1"   Grid.Row="4" >
                                    <Label Text=":"  TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  >
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="4"   Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Qty}" x:Name="Quantity" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" MaxLines="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>                 
    </Grid>
    <Frame Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  BorderColor="Transparent" Margin="10,2,10,2" Padding="5">
        <Frame  BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderColor="Green" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <Frame.CornerRadius>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="35" />
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="40" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Frame.CornerRadius>
            <Grid >
                <Image Source="dialerbg2.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="30"></Image>               
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Image Source="cellphone.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="25" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Phone" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightBlue" >
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text=":"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                        <Label x:Name="PhoneNumber" Grid.Column="2" Text="+919605209575"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" >
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                        <Image Source="caller.png"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Column="3"></Image>                 
                    </Grid>                  
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

How to make this similar on every screen size? Should I add scrollview? Iam bit confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can setting different size of text in each device by the different screenHeight.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT can you give me some guidlines about setting diffrent text sizes according to device screen size? I think that will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your design within a ScrollView.

In smaller devices your list will not have sufficient space to display all elements, so it will resize and adjust to fill the available space.

Comment: But is there any option without the scrollview?like  the same view with smaller text. I put scrollview..But it takes much space

Answer (score 0):

> can you give me some guidlines about setting diffrent text sizes
>   according to device screen size? I think that will solve my problem

For example:

```
    nfloat screenSize = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height;

    // 5, 5s, SE, 5C  320 * 568

    nfloat iphone5sHeight = 568;

    if (screenSize <= iphone5sHeight)
    {
        //set the fontSize
    }
    else {
        //set the fontSize for higher screen
    }
```

You can have a look at these two threads for more idea: [different-uifont-sizes-for-different-ios-devices-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981319/different-uifont-sizes-for-different-ios-devices-in-swift) and [how-to-ios-item-and-font-sizes-scaling-as-screen-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495725/how-to-ios-item-and-font-sizes-scaling-as-screen-size/53496831#53496831)