# Change Label Font Size Only If Current Font Size Doesn't Fit

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label(actually 2) inside a recent Xcode 11 and Swift 5 time calculator app. So basically, the functionality is when the user enters a number, presses a button, etc., the two labels change their label text. I have 2 testing iPhones: my 6s Plus iPhone and my old iPhone 5, which has a screen that's almost only half of my iPhone 6s Plus's screen size. When I run my code on the 6s iPhone, everything works alright, and the label fonts work perfectly: [image]

But when I run it on my iPhone 5...:
[image]

The label text goes out of the label. How can I resolve this issue? I have read some other stack overflow questions, but nothing worked. Some things I've tried are this:

```swift
ansLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20)
        ansLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        ansLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        ansLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
        ansLabel.clipsToBounds = true
```

This above code just set my ui label's text to 0.1.

Any help is appreciated
P.S. Remember I only want a text resize if the current text size doesn't fit. If the current text size does fit, then the job won't need to be done.

Comment: I think your question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138926/how-to-add-dynamic-font-size-about-multi-device-in-xcode-story-board)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
let IS_IPHONE5 = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 568.0
if IS_IPHONE5{
        ansLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 18)
 }else{
        ansLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20)
 }
```